# Format button text in Cocoa application

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos

I am re-visiting my calculator application and am now trying to tighten up the interface to make it look nicer so I was wondering how or if it's possible to format the text of a button.

For example, I currently have the '1' button with a plain gray control and black character in the center of the button, but is there a way to move the character to, say, the upper left corner of the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NSButton's [-setAttributedTitle:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSButton_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method to send it an attributed string. for basic formatting.

For anything "fancy", however, you'll likely have to subclass NSButtonCell and handle the drawing yourself using one of the "draw with attributes" methods with a custom [NSParagraphStyle](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSParagraphStyle_Class/Reference/Reference.html) as one of the attributes for paragraph alignment, etc.